Force Viewport Visibility to Respect Render Visibility
I use the viewport render to do all my look dev, and lighting, so I make things enabled or disabled based on what I need for that render layer/scene. But of course when I go to actually render the scene, none of that matters if I haven't adjusted the Render Visibility!
Is there a way to use a script that would automatically create a driver for every objects so the viewport visibility drives the render visibility? I end up doing this by hand, and it takes forever! Open to any other solution to this issue.

I think you should split your questions into two separate questions. It should  be one question per question.

Fair. I've edited it to be more direct regarding my needs. Thank you!

If you are using view layers, you should use collections. You can enable and disable collections per view layer. That will hide objects everywhere.

That actually doesn’t work, because I can’t add key frames to the visibility of a collection unless I make it an instance. So, that seems a bit excessive to have to make a collection for every object and then an instance of that collection in order for me to animate its visibility. I just need the viewport visibility and the render visibility to always be the same. I don’t even know why we have both options? It’s been the most frustrating part of rendering in Blender.

I don't think this question will get answered. I think this is an XY problem. You should ask a new question detailing your actual goal and providing full context about what you actually want to do. You should probably set up view layers and if you need to render different ones at different times, you can animate "Use for Rendering" property for them. Or you can animate visibility per object without touching view layers, then it's quite easy to sync viewport and render visibility with Python if you want that.
